# mypy: Untyped decorator makes function "main" untyped for FastAPI routes

Tags: python, fastapi, mypy

Consider the following:

```py
@app.post("/")
def main(body: RequestBody) -> dict[str, object]:
    pass
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Untyped decorator makes function "main" untyped  [misc]mypy(error)

Couldn't find anything online about it. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: The decorator has no type hints, so `mypy` won't assume that the original type isn't changed. (Rememberer, this is equivalent to defining `main`, then defining `main = app.post("/")(main)`. If `mypy` doesn't know what `app.post("/")(main)` returns, it can't make any assumptions about the type of `main`.)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I just installed FastAPI and it's fully type-annotated, and tried your code, and can't get your untyped issue. `from fastapi import FastAPI; app = FastAPI()`

Comment: Try that with a `--dissalow-untyped-decorators`, I can reproduce. Curious to know if there's a resolution for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `Python › Analysis: Type Checking Mode` setting from `strict` to `standard` fixed this for me.